# Different outcome calculating MD5 hash in Javascript and C++

Tags: javascript, c++

I am trying to calculate an MD5 hash for a certain value in Javascript and in C++ but the different programming languages are giving different outputs at times. As it does not happen constantly I am guessing it has something to do with rounding errors.

In Javascript I am calculating the value as follows:

```
let calculatedTotal = 0;
blocks.forEach((block) => {
   calculatedTotal += Math.floor(block.standard_deviation * 1000);
});
```

In C++ using rapidJson I am doing:

```
for (rapidjson::Value::ConstValueIterator j = blocks.Begin(); j != blocks.End(); ++j) {
    float val = (*j)["standard_deviation"].GetFloat();
    sumToCalculteHashOver += int(std::floor(val * 1000));
}
```

As shown in C++ I am using a float.

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this?

Comment: can you post a [mcve] ?

Comment: Don't rely on floating points, it's (calculated) value is an approximation.

Comment: @Caramiriel thanks I am going to try to work with that knowledge see if I can solve this issue somehow.

Comment: That does not look like MD5 at all...

Comment: @rustyx read the question please. I am trying to determine why I am getting different outcomes. It is MD5 related to offer context. But I figured it out already thanks to Caramiriel.

Comment: Javascript uses doubles, not floats IIRC. @Caramiriel has a point (floating-point is an approximation _of real numbers_) but it's deterministic.

Comment: @MSalters thanks for the extra information. I already managed to solve the issue by using integer values only.

Comment: Note that integer arithmetic is also an approximation: 7/3 is _approximately_ 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this thanks to @Caramiriel.

The issue has, as I kinda expected, to do with the precision of floating point numbers in C++.

Using an integer value in my calculations worked. For me that meant I needed to make these changes.

Javascript:

```
let calculatedTotal = 0;
blocks.forEach((block) => {
   calculatedTotal += Math.floor(block.standard_deviation) * 1000;
});
```

C++:

```
for (rapidjson::Value::ConstValueIterator j = blocks.Begin(); j != blocks.End(); ++j) {
    int val = int(std::floor((*j)["standard_deviation"].GetFloat()));
    sumToCalculteHashOver += int(std::floor(val * 1000));
}
```